# How To Keep Button From Moving On Android ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm working on a gallery activity and I've run into some trouble. I can't seem to get the button (which is outside the viewpager's xml) to remain static. When swiping it creates what appears to be a duplicate button, even though it's outside of the viewpager's xml. I've attached an image that captures the issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="eqlogic.annswingsandthings.Activity_Gallery">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/gallery_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/send_photo_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</RelativeLayout>

public class GalleryPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    static Context m_Context;
    public GalleryPagerAdapter
            (FragmentManager fm, Context context)
    {
        super(fm);
        m_Context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        return GalleryBackgroundFragment.NewInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(GalleryDataHandler.m_Bitmaps != null)
            return GalleryDataHandler.m_Bitmaps.size();

        else return 0;
    }
}

public class GalleryBackgroundFragment extends Fragment {

    BitmapDrawable m_Bitmap;
    public static GalleryBackgroundFragment NewInstance(int i)
    {
        try
        {
            GalleryBackgroundFragment gallery = new GalleryBackgroundFragment();
            gallery.m_Bitmap = new BitmapDrawable
                    (Activity_Gallery.m_LocalActivity.getResources(),
                            GalleryDataHandler.m_Bitmaps.get(i));
            gallery.setRetainInstance(true);
            return gallery;
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        { Log.d("Error:", e.toString()); e.printStackTrace(); return null; }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView
            (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, container, false);

        view.setBackground(m_Bitmap);
        return view;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice food!!! (sorry I had to say it. Can also add the adapter code as well?

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Adapter Code On The Way.

Comment: Updated the code to include the adapter and fragment.

Comment: Can you also provide the xml for `R.layout.activity_gallery`?

Comment: That's the one at the top.

Comment: So you are using the same layout for both the adapter and its children?

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed now. I totally am.

Comment: No problems. I guess I will lose my mind too if I see that much food :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure on how to go about it now. Should I have a separate xml layout containing just the view pager?

Comment: @hoomi - Nevermind, disregard, I just made a new blank layout. Thanks for your time, I have no idea why I didn't realize what was going on. Been running on little sleep trying to get this done.